# How to customize the error message when inserting image into the Froala WYSIWYG editing area

Tags: froala

I would like to use Froala in my web app. I am testing its image insert button and would like to limit the image size to 1M. When I drop an image larger than that, I see an error message:

```
Something went wrong. Please try again.
```

I would like to show something such as

```
Image cannot be larger than 1M.

Image type is not supported.
```

Is this doable in Froala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following inside the [`image.error`](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events#image.error) event:

```js
var $popup = editor.popups.get('image.insert');
var $layer = $popup.find('.fr-image-progress-bar-layer');
$layer.find('h3').text('Your message');
```